# Windows 8: Enable smooth scrolling

Tags: windows-8, scrolling

Does Windows 8 have a smooth scrolling feature?

I have a Chrome extension that works for the browser but was hoping to implement it everywhere.

Comment: I don't see anything so far. Was there anything in Windows 7 for this?

Comment: All I can think of as a system-wide setting is the "Smooth scroll list boxes" option under Visual/Performance Options.

Comment: @Karan I have that click, that's why I asked because it seems like they have a feature but I can't tell a difference with it checked or unchecked.

Comment: Might depend on the graphics card. TBH doesn't seem to make all that big a difference on my system as well.

Comment: You can change the setting in mouse properties "wheel" tab, set vertical to 1, it will help, but more than likely you will need a third party mouse and driver that allows for more control.

Comment: For the ignorant amongst us, what is "smooth scrolling"?

Comment: Smooth scrolling is just a smooth transition when scrolling versus the windows default of skipping "x" number of lines which is choppy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a specific Smooth Scrolling mouse option, but you can essentially do just that.

In Mouse Properties, under the wheel tab, reducing the number of lines to 1 (for both horizontal and vertical).  While this may not be exactly what you are looking for, it will make your scrolling a lot smoother.

Sources: [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/windows-8-smooth-scroll-is-not-smooth/9922caf8-4c69-499a-b2ef-8cabe7d8a496) and a video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ec_m1HtZeVU).

Edit:  There is a utility called [TwoFingerScroll](http://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/downloads/detail?name=TwoFingerScroll_1_0_6.zip&can=2&q=) that enables smooth scrolling for Synaptics based Trackpads.  [Source](http://www.guidingtech.com/9229/neat-ways-to-scroll-smoothly-on-windows/)

Comment: It's a shame for Windows, this has to be the only answer. There are ultra smooth mouses from Logitech, I wonder when those will be supported...

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Mouse and Keyboard Center 2.3 (formerly IntelliPoint IntelliType Pro)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42510) from their website and it will smooth out any setup.

It works with any mouse (at least any mouse I've used so far).

Comment: What do you mean by **it will smooth out any setup** ??

Comment: You can merge your accounts here Brendan: http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: It only works with Microsoft devices (at least not MY mouse...)